# Print all the combinations of elements in matrix of size m * n

Tags: java, matrix

### Print all the combinations of elements in matrix of size m * n

#### Sample Example:

```
1  3  5  
2  6  7
```

#### Expected Output:

```
1 , 3 , 5 
1 , 3 , 7 
1 , 6 , 5
1 , 6 , 7 
2 , 3 , 5
2 , 3 , 7
2 , 6 , 5
2 , 6 , 7
```

#### Rules:

- Every combination starts from left of matrix and proceeds towards right. It may switch rows though.
- Every combination should have number of elements equal to number of columns.
- A combination can't have an element from the same column present twice.
- Number of columns and rows could vary. So solution has to be generic.

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  class Combination {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  int row, col, i, j;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix:\n");
  row = in.nextInt();
  col = in.nextInt();

  int first[][] = new int[row][col];
  System.out.println("Enter the elements if matric m*n:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
          first[i][j] = in.nextInt();
      }
  }
  System.out.println("Matrix:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
          System.out.print(first[i][j] + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
  // Final Logic from here...
  System.out.println("\nOut Matrix:\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
          for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
              System.out.println(first[i][0] + "," + first[j][1] + ","
                      + first[k][2]+"\n");
          }
      }
  }
   /* while (i < 2) {
      j = 0;
      while (j < 2) {
          k = 0;
          while (k < 2) {
              System.out.println(first[i][0] + "," + first[j][1] + ","
                      + first[k][2]);
              k++;
          }
          j++;
      }
      i++;
  }*/
  in.close();
  }
  }
  ```

Works good for specific input but not able to do it dynamic....Need Help..

### Thanks in Advance......

Comment: What do you mean by you are not able to do it dynamic, but it works for specific input? I see that the user inputs the number of rows and columns at the beginning of the program, so what else would you want to dynamize?

Comment: it works for above given input i made some changes on the place of 2 in final logic  replaced it with row , but then i give it input 2*4 matrix it doesn't works....

Comment: Thank you. Is the display order of the combinations important? To illustrate my question. With your example of expected output, would it still be a valid answer if the element:  2 , 6 , 7 appeared at the top of the output or in the middle of it?

Comment: Yup no issue it should just print the above combinations ...and i am trying a generic code thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion as follows:

```
...
    // Final Logic from here...
    System.out.println("\nOut Matrix:\n");
    int[] outputRow = new int[col];
    print(0, row, col, first, outputRow);

}

private static void print(int j, int row, int col, int[][] first, int[] outputRow) {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        outputRow[j] = first[i][j];
        // recursively continue to populate outputRow until we reach the last column (j == col -1)
        if (j < col - 1) {
            print(j + 1, row, col, first, outputRow);               
        }
        // we have reached the last column (j == col -1) so now we could print current permutation
        if (j == col - 1) {
            for (int k = 0; k < col; k++) {
                System.out.print(" " + outputRow[k]);                   
            }
            System.out.println();                   
        }
    }
}
```

Here we process one column per recursion call starting with `j==0`.

`outputRow` stores the current permutation and is updated recursively.

When we recursively reach the last column then it's time to print the current permutation.

Comment: You don't HAVE to use recursion, it's just one way

Comment: @SergeyPauk  I am not getting how the loop is working  after printing 1 3 5 ...can u plzzz provide some more explanation.........

Comment: After printing `1 3 5`  variable`i` is incremented by one and becomes `1`  then you update `outputRow`'s last element with `first[1][2]` (previous value was `first[0][2]`) so that current output row is different from the previous one only in it's last element.

Comment: @SergeyPauk
j=2 i=1 
Row//j=2
outputRow[2]=7
1 3 7 
j=1 i=1 

Row//j=1
outputRow[1]=6
j=2 i=0 

Row//j=2
outputRow[2]=5
1 6 5 
j=2 i=1 

Row//j=2
outputRow[2]=7
1 6 7 
j=0 i=1 

Row//j=0
outputRow[0]=2
j=1 i=0 

Row//j=1
outputRow[1]=3
j=2 i=0 

Row//j=2
outputRow[2]=5
2 3 5 
j=2 i=1 

Row//j=2
outputRow[2]=7
2 3 7 
j=1 i=1 

Row//j=1
outputRow[1]=6
j=2 i=0 

Row//j=2
outputRow[2]=5
2 6 5 
j=2 i=1 

Row//j=2
outputRow[2]=7
2 6 7 
Can you please explain me again about what happens after value of j becomes 2 i.e. j=2

Comment: is it like stack... but not getting how the values of j becomes again 1...? plzz explain me i am confused,,,,

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible approach

```
void printCombos(){
    visit(0,-1,"");
}

void visit(int r,int c,String s){
    if(c!=a[0].length-1)
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            visit(i,c+1,s+" - "+a[i][c+1]);
    else
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

considering the matrix as a tree to deep-visit. Given an imaginary root * these are the edges (*,1) - (*,2) - (1,3) - (1,6) - (2,3) - (2,6) and so on

```
* --- 1 -- 3 -- 5
  \     \/   \/
   \    /\   /\
    \ 2 -- 6 -- 7
```

with 5 and 7 being the leaves.

Answer (score 0):

First create one more method :

```
private static void increasePointerArray(int[] poinerArray, int row) 
{
    for (int i = poinerArray.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(poinerArray[i] == row-1) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            poinerArray[i] = poinerArray[i] +1;
            for (int j = i+1; j < poinerArray.length; j++) {
                poinerArray[j] = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in final logic section put below code :

```
int[] poinerArray = new int[col];
int[] MaxArray = new int[col];
List<int[]> resultList = new ArrayList<int[]>();

Arrays.fill(poinerArray, 0);
Arrays.fill(MaxArray, row-1);

while(!Arrays.equals(poinerArray, MaxArray)) {
    resultList.add(poinerArray.clone());
    increasePointerArray(poinerArray, row);
}
resultList.add(poinerArray.clone());

System.out.println("Printing desired result : ");

for (int[] ks : resultList) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        sb.append(first[ks[j]][j]+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    sb = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Permutations{
    public static String strings="";
    public static ArrayList<String> out=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void gen(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> x,int index){
        for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
            if(i>0){
                String[] parts=strings.split(",");
                strings="";
                for(int k=0;k<parts.length;k++){
                    if(k==index)
                        break;
                    strings=strings+parts[k]+",";
                }
            }
            if(index==x.get(0).size()-1){
                strings=strings+(x.get(i).get(index));
                out.add(strings);
            }
            else
                strings=strings+(x.get(i).get(index))+",";
            if(index+1<=x.get(0).size()-1)
                gen(x,index+1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> x=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while(true){
            line=br.readLine();
            if(line.contentEquals("")) break;
            String[] parts=line.split(" ");
            x.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
                x.get(x.size()-1).add(parts[i]);
            }
        }
        gen(x,0);
        for(int i=0;i<out.size();i++){
            System.out.println(out.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This code is works. Its very generic and quite simple to understand. I did column wise permutations on the 2D Array.